# Nested methods in Ruby Helper

Tags: ruby, haml, middleman

I'm working on a project in MiddleMan. Trying to pass the results of a method as the parameters of another method. I'm running into all kinds of syntax issues with the commas and parens. Everything looks right to me, am I crazy? Thanks in advance!

The method call that I'm having trouble with is `create_campus_subnav()`

```
module SubnavHelper

  def create_subnav_link ( label, link="" )
    if link == ""
      link = label
    end
    return "          <li id='item-#{link}'><a class='title' id='link-#{link}'>#{label}</a></li>"
  end

  def create_subnav (*links)
    subnav = "\
    <nav class='nav-sub'>\
      <div class='nav-wrap'>\
        <ul class='nav-list'>"

    links.each do |attr,val|
      subnav += " attr: " + attr;
      subnav += " val: " + val;
      # subnav += args["attr"] + "\n"
    end 

    subnav += "\
        </ul>\
      </div>\
    </nav>"
    return subnav
  end

  def create_campus_subnav
      subnav = create_subnav ( 
        create_subnav_link ("Campus Overview", "Overview"), 
        create_subnav_link ("About", "About"),  
        create_subnav_link ("Admissions"), 
        create_subnav_link ("Career Services" "CareerServices"),       
        create_subnav_link ("Schedules, Tuition & Fees" "Tuition"),         
        create_subnav_link ("Financial Assistance & Scholarships" "FinancialAssistance"),         
        create_subnav_link ("Faculty")      
      )
      puts subnav
  end
end
```

And the errors:

```
/dev/config.rb:54:in `require': /gia/dev/helpers/subnav_helper.rb:36: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')' (SyntaxError)
        create_subnav_link ("Campus Overview", "Overview"), 
                                              ^
/dev/helpers/subnav_helper.rb:36: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
        create_subnav_link ("Campus Overview", "Overview"), 
                                                          ^
/dev/helpers/subnav_helper.rb:37: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
        create_subnav_link ("About", "About"),  
                                             ^
/dev/helpers/subnav_helper.rb:37: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
        create_subnav_link ("About", "About"),  
                                                      ^
/dev/helpers/subnav_helper.rb:39: syntax error, unexpected tLPAREN_ARG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
        create_subnav_link ("Career Services" "...
                            ^
/dev/helpers/subnav_helper.rb:39: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end
...er Services" "CareerServices"),       
...                               ^
/dev/helpers/subnav_helper.rb:41: syntax error, unexpected tLPAREN_ARG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
        create_subnav_link ("Financial Assistance & Schol...
                            ^
/dev/helpers/subnav_helper.rb:41: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end
...rships" "FinancialAssistance"),         
...                               ^
/dev/helpers/subnav_helper.rb:43: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
```

Comment: I've tried doing it all on one line, I've tried "do" and "end" (but not sure if I'm doing that right), I've tried omitting parens and commas, I've tried with and without wrapping up the args as an array or in parentheses.

Comment: I don't know if this is related but method calls should not have a space before the arg parens.

Comment: It definitely was introducing some ambiguity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def create_subnav (*links)
  subnav = "\
    <nav class='nav-sub'>\
      <div class='nav-wrap'>\
        <ul class='nav-list'>"

        links.each do |attr,val|
          subnav += " attr: " + attr;
          subnav += " val: " + val;
          # subnav += args["attr"] + "\n"
        end 

        subnav += "\
        </ul>\
      </div>\
    </nav>"
    return subnav
end

def create_campus_subnav
  subnav = create_subnav(
                          create_subnav_link("Campus Overview", "Overview"),
                          create_subnav_link("About", "About"),
                          create_subnav_link("Admissions"),
                          create_subnav_link("Career Services" "CareerServices"),
                          create_subnav_link("Schedules, Tuition & Fees" "Tuition"),
                          create_subnav_link("Financial Assistance & Scholarships" "FinancialAssistance"),
                          create_subnav_link("Faculty")
                         )
                         puts subnav
end
```

This will do it for you, but I think I would prefer the first entry to the argument list to be on the same line.

Comment: So it's all about the space before the `(` ? Unbelievable.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the built-in view helpers, like `content_tag` instead of doing a bunch of string concatenation:

```
def subnav(*links)
  content_tag(:nav, 
    content_tag(:div,
      content_tag(:ul,
        links.map do |link|
          content_tag :a, link.text, :href => link.href do
        end.join, :class => 'nav-list'),
      :class => 'nav-wrap'
    ),
    :class => 'nav-sub'
  )
end
```

Note: I just took a guess at the structure of your 'links' variable, but I think you get the idea